# Consider four sets: $A = \left[-1, 0\right); B = \{-1, 3\}; C = \left(-\infty, 4\right); D = \left(0, 2\right]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I simplify $\left(A \cup B \cup D\right) \cap \left(C \setminus D\right)$ and represent it using set notation.

I understand that:
$\left(A \cup B \cup D\right)$ = $\left[-1, 0\right) \cup \{3\} \cup \left(0, 2\right]$
and
$\left(C \setminus D\right)$ = $\left(−\infty,0\right] \cup \left(2, 4\right)$

But I had trouble (wasn't clear) with the simplifying part "$\cap$" of the two.

Comment: I know this is an assignment question due tomorrow (I tutor your course at the University of Auckland). You should explain what you've tried and where you're stuck (rather than expecting an answer straight away).

Comment: I'll try and edit the question to show what I had trouble with. Thank you for pointing the crucial part of this whole system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(A \cup B \cup D\right) = [-1,0) \cup (0,2] \cup \{3\}$$

$$\left(C \setminus D\right) = (-\infty,0] \cup(2,4)$$

Now the common parts:

$$\left(A \cup B \cup D\right) \cap \left(C \setminus D\right)\\=[-1,0)\cup{\{3\}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(A \cup B \cup D) \cap (C \setminus D)=(A \cup B) \cap C$

Also $(A\cup B)\subset C$, so

$(A \cup B \cup D) \cap (C \setminus D)= [-1,0)\cup \{3\}$